# convert all values of map to string in go

Tags: go

I am using an application written in go that takes a list of keys and extracts the values from data if that key exists in the data.

However, this function only accepts string values - and unfortunately my data has both arrays and numbers as values (this can't be changed, it's coming from Azure OIDC login)

So rather than complain I thought I'd roll up my sleeves and try and fix it myself (having never written a single line of "go" before )

so, this is the original function

```
func extractMetadata(logger log.Logger, allClaims map[string]interface{}, claimMappings map[string]string) (map[string]string, error) {
    metadata := make(map[string]string)
    for source, target := range claimMappings {
        if value := getClaim(logger, allClaims, source); value != nil {
            strValue, ok := value.(string)
            if !ok {
                return nil, fmt.Errorf("error converting claim '%s' to string", source)
            }

            metadata[target] = strValue
        }
    }
    return metadata, nil
}
```

I believe that the line in question is

`strValue, ok := value.(string)`

as that's where I'm getting the error.

If I were to change this to

`strValue, ok := fmt.Sprintf("%v",value)` would that (a) work and (b) be safe ? ..

(fmt is already imported by the code)

Are there more elegant solutions available in go ?

Comment: `fmt.Sprintf("%v",value)` safely formats any value as a string. A simpler call is  `fmt.Sprint(value)`.   Both of calls use the default format for the type and that may or may not be the format you want.

Comment: thanks very much for the comment - if you want to add it as an answer I'll accept it ! thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`value.(string)` is doing **type assertion** not **type conversion**
It checks if `value` is a string and returns the same along with a boolean flag.

To convert an interface to a string you can format it using `Sprintf` which will return a single string value,

`strValue := fmt.Sprint("%v", value)`

Safety would depend on your application. If you can later parse the data and interpret the numbers and arrays for what they are you should be fine.

As it looks like a metadata store to simple store information, formatting strings should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

`fmt.Sprintf("%v",value)` safely formats any value as a string. A simpler call is `fmt.Sprint(value)`. Both of calls use the default format for the type and that may or may not be the format you want.